# TextBox.text cant be changed by code for next session

Tags: vb.net

In VB Studio 2010 Express. I am trying to change the text in a textbox (via a button), so that the new string appears next time the app is run. The 'text' will change for the current session, but when I close and re-run, the 'text' is back to its original text.
eg

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim chg As String
  chg = InputBox("CHANGE TEXT", "CHANGE TO:", )
  Me.TextBox1.Text = chg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`My.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx) to save values between sessions of the application.

Right click the name of your project in Solution Explorer, select Properties, then Settings tab. Create a new setting that we'll call it `Foo` (for purposes of this answer), of type String and scope User. Give it a default value in the Value column, if needed.

Now you can store the current value of `TextBox1.Text` in the `Foo` setting when the application is closed (e.g. in FormClosing event):

```
My.Settings.Foo = TextBox1.Text
```

To get the value of Foo from previous session, in your form's Load event (or any method that runs when the application starts) add this line:

```
TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Foo
```

Comment: also dont forget to call `My.Settings.Save` after setting `My.Settings.Foo`

Comment: @JasonBayldon, settings are automatically saved right before application shutdown in VB. So you don't really have to explicitly call save.

Comment: Ah right, unless ts dechecked from the application framework properties.